# Ajax based javascript photo galleries, photo sliders, carousels

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, photo-gallery

All photo gallery libraries read HTML DOM for show photos  and this is causing unnecesary resource usage for non-clicked photos.I want to have photo galleries which only load thumbs then loads real image by ajax request from server.

Is there such as photo galleries ?

Comment: This is not fully correct. The approach mentioned is used by most lightbox–plugins. Usually the `href` attribute of a link around a thumbnail is used to load the big image. Examples: http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/ or http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/ and many others.

Comment: And images are not loaded with AJAX, but only by changing src atribute of the image, which loads it.